# How to end HTML code midway?

Tags: php, html, xss, code-injection

I was trying Html injection on my own website. However, I wasn't able to completely change my page (I mean I wasn't able to change it after the part where my previous input was displayed in the current page. I understand that I won't be able to change anything before this). I was able to add my own fields and all but my original html stuff remained there.

I tried to put < /body > </html> at the end of my html injection code but that didn't stop the page from showing the html elements after my "fake" </html > tag. Of course, I checked this on a normal html page and there too things after </html > are displayed. Can I overcome this problem? Like is there a stronger tag that forces the browser to stop looking into the html file after a tag?
(I am new to this, please use simple language in answering! thanks.)

To clarify , consider the following:

```html
<--! Here $oldMessage holds the string that was searched in the previous page.
Like a search engine. 
This page is of the search result -->

  <p>Your search for
    <?php echo "$oldMessage";> gave the following result: </p>
<p>
<!-- Some lines of HTML+php -->
</p>
<p>
Thank You for Visiting my website!
</p>
</body>
</html>


<!-- My search is: '</p>
<p>
<form>
  Uid:
 <input type="text" name="uid" >
<br>
  Password:
  <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>' 
so when this gets echoed by $oldMessage, it tries to add userid
and password field by GET method and tries to end the html 
but the problem is, rest of the original html is also displayed which
makes it fishy for unknown user that this is fake(I am just 
trying this out of curiosity, not doing anything malicious 
to anyone) -->
```

Comment: really no idea what you are talking about

Comment: It would help if you included some code to better explain your question. Because really, no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Done adding more info. Check it out.

Comment: In short: you don't need to stop processing html (you can't anyway). It's enough if for example you create a `<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%">your new content</div>`.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the rest of the HTML of the target page, you might be able to open a div with a style of "display:none" and don't close that tag. Then, whatever comes after would be nested in that invisible div.

In case the target page has unmatched closing div tags,  you can try opening many of said tags to make sure nothing gets shown.

Otherwise you may be able to inject JavaScript to hide anything that follows your last tag.

To answer the question more directly, the closing body or html tag marks the end of the document, but the actual behavior of the browser depends each vendor. Browsers often try to guess what the best way to render HTML is when it malformed. This is called Tag Soup: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup